# What are Tanya and Nefesh Hachaim coming to answer that wasn't clear beforehand

Tags: torah-study

What questions are they coming to answer.
What was the puropse of these sefarim that are made a big deal about compared to other seforim of the time which are seen as just toras of a particular genre like noam elimelech or kedushas levi. Or even older seforim like kuzari, and chovos halevovos.

Comment: Have you read either work?

Comment: I haven't learned nefesh hachaim so I can't comment on this but it's clearly explained in Tanya the question it is meant to answer. A good start would be learning it. All the best.

Comment: AFAIK, the Tanya was the first systematic attempt to lay out the intellectual basis for the Chassidic movement. The Baal HaTanya did such a convincing job that R' Chayim of Volozhin felt the need to write Nefesh Hachayim as a rebuttal to the Tanya, laying  out the anti-Chassidic view of those issues.